# Angular: Why in an 'if statement' you can use a const as a boolean?

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement

I've found a lot of examples in Angular using an if statement the following way.

Here the if statement is checking if the "id" const exists or not. If it exists it executes the service task. However, "id" is not a boolean, is a number, so I don't understand why it is analyzed as a boolean.

```
alumno: Alumno = new Alumno();

constructor(private service: AlumnoService, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const id: number = +params.get('id');
      if(id){
        this.service.ver(id).subscribe(alumno => this.alumno = alumno);
      }
    })
```

I suspect that if "id" is not null, then it is analyzed as true, and if it is null is analyzed as false, but I don't understand why.

Comment: In this case `if (id)` means if `id` has a value or if it is defined. If `id` is either `null` or `undefined` the service call will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

All variables and objects in JS can be used as a boolean, but I would not always reccomend it.

Read [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) to see what is considered truthy/falsey in JS.

In your example, `id` is queried like that to chec whether it is `null` or `undefined`, but it will also be falsey if it is `0`, so it is usually better to do more explicit checks in `if` statements, especially for numbers.

Comment: Also this ECMAScript spec section: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toboolean

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is clear now. 
I am used to Java programming so I didn´t know this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(variable)
```

this will be true whenever **variable** has some value it can be string , boolean true or any positive or negative number but should not be null , false, '', undefined, NaN, 0

Same is written in documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else